# Instantly detect an input being checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, input

Say that I have an input with the type "checkbox"

```
<input type='checkbox' id='checker'>
```

I need to be able to detect instantly whether this box is checked, without a button click or function call. Checking and unchecking the box will lighten or darken text. How do I constantly check whether the box is unchecked or not IN VANILLA JAVASCRIPT? I need to be able to do this, preferably without an infinite for-loop that'll crash the page. I know the method for it

```
var value=document.getElementById('checker').checked;
```

but I need a way to constantly see whether it has been checked or not without reloading the page using vanilla javascript. Please help!

EDIT: I am also considering using two radio buttons, one with value true and the other with value false, but I still need a way of seeing which one is checked.

Comment: why no function call? using `onclick` sounds pretty handy in this case

Comment: @depperm Because I need to know when it's clicked, but then if it's clicked again(unselected) I need to be able to tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rrath8tg/1/:

```
// checkbox is a reference to the element
checkbox.onchange = function() {
     if(this.checked) {
         // do something when checked
     }
};
```

Or `onchange` on checkbox element.

Answer (score 1):

You could use just CSS providing that the text you want to change is on the same level in the DOM:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checker">
<span id="sometext">Lorem ipsum...</span>
```

CSS:

```
input#checker:checked + span#sometext {
    color:#ff0000; /* Red - highlighted */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Event listeners and event delegation will help you

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT' && e.target.type == 'checkbox' && e.target.checked) {
    alert('Checked!');
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

- [`e.target.nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) returns the tag name of the clicked element
- `e.target.type` returns its type
- [`e.target.checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) returns whether the clicked element became checked

Works for all checkboxes on the page (you can also check `e.taget.id` whether you have the right one).

---

### An exmaple using radio buttons

In this case a `change` event listener is more appropriate, as you can *click* on a radio button without *changing* it.

```js
document.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT' && e.target.type == 'radio' && e.target.checked) {
    alert(e.target.id); // returns either `yes` or `no`.
  }
});
```

```html
<label><input id="yes" name="radio0" type="radio" />Yes</label>
<label><input id="no" name="radio0" type="radio" />No</label>
```

---

### Why event delegation?

If you attach the event listeners to `document` rather than to a specific `input`, there are a few advantages:

- No need to wrap all the code in `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){})` or something similar. It doesn’t matter, whether the content has loaded, this event will also fire and the correct target will always be provided.
- It works for any number of input boxes. You don’t need to bind an event listener to every single input box.

It is a bit advanced, though. If you want to change the elements next to the input boxes, *no matter which input box has been clicked*, you’ll have to do this with `nextElementSibling`, `previousElementSibling`, `parentNode`, `children`, etc.

Comment: how would I edit this to grab only a certain checkbox with the id "foo"?

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon check for the ID with `e.target.id=='foo'` or bind a listener directly.